# How to put image div container over another div, yet keep it clickable?

Tags: css, image, html, containers, layer

I want to put my image over accordion div container and keep it clickable, so my image override it only visually. How I can do that?

My page that I need to [edit is there](http://podstrigis.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82/). 
That's what I want to make my page look like:

THANKS IN ADVANCE![image]

Comment: The top image needs to be a `png` and you need to use `position: absolute;` and a `z-index` so it sits on top

Comment: I have added z-index:2 and position: absolute tags and my image overrides my accordion block completely (it's not clickable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is possible in most browsers with CSS (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IOS, Android. A full list available [HERE](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events))

```
img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eyEkj/1/)

Not supported in IE10 or below.

There are also number of Javascript solutions including [THIS ONE](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit) using Jquery that are usable in IE.

Comment: There is no answer in your answer, just links. Maybe you should paste the relevant JS here and describe a bit.

Comment: @feeela "pointer-events: none;" How is that not an answer? I provided a link to somebody else's Javascript solution as further reading

Comment: Wow, had not heard of this one. Thanks for mentioning it. Obviously not really ready for widespread use, but nice to know. Very interesting JS solution, too. Still, I prefer to avoid fancy stuff like this for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to sit the image over the top and have the links clickable. The only solution I can think of is to slice the image into two parts, placing one above the accordion and one to the left. Even doing that, though, will mean the blue +s will not be clickable, as the image will have to sit over them. And getting the two parts of the sliced image to match wouldn't be fun, either. (I'm sure some old browser or two would mess it up for you.)

Honestly, my suggestion is to rethink this, as it's not practical for the web. I would suggest placing the whole image as a background on the accordion and living with the girl's hand pointing to the links without actually hovering over them.

Comment: I'm new to website building and I thought it was possible. Well, then I'll stick to your suggestion above. Thanks!